# Gauss-Seidel linear system solver - cases when it is unstable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

I have a Gauss-Seidel linear system solver that has always been able to solve many kinds of linear systems. However, it struggles when solving this very simple system:
$$
22.7986\,x_1 + 4981.2903 \,x_2 = 25.48488 \\ 10047.4775\,x_1 -4981.2903\,x_2 = 6.05489
$$

My initial guess is $(0.01,0.01)$ but I have tried changing it to other values and it's still is not converging.

Basically the new guess that the algorithm computes in each iteration consistently becomes larger, and so is the error. I was checking the Burden book to see if there are special cases in which Gauss-Seidel does not converge but there is little on that.

I know that there exists a solution to the above system because I have solved it using Excel's functionality to invert matrices and then use matrix multiplication. Particularly, the solution to the system is $(0.003131967,0.005101786)$.

Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Cited from http://www.cfd-online.com/Wiki/Gauss-Seidel_method : "The method will always converge if the matrix A is strictly or irreducibly diagonally dominant. [...] The Gauss-Seidel method sometimes converges even if this condition is not satisfied. It is necessary, however, that the diagonal terms in the matrix are greater (in magnitude) than the other terms."

Comment: The Gauss-Seidel method would never converge for this system since the spectral radius for both forward and backward version is about $440$ which is much larger than $1$. So the help would be: do not use Gauss-Seidel.

Answer (score -1):

The problem can be solved by rewriting the equations in the following way
4981.2903X2+22.7986X1=25.48488

-4981.2903X2+10047.4775X1 = 6.05489

Step 1: Assume X1 = 0 in the first equation and calculate X2 = 0.005116

Step 2: Taking X2 = 0.005116, calculate X1 from the second equation X1 = 0.003136

Step 3: Taking X1 = 0.003136, calculate X2 from the first equation X2 = 0.0051018

Step 4: Taking X2 = 0.0051018, calculate X1 from the second equation X1 = 0.003131

So the final answer is X1 = 0.003131 and x2 = 0.0051018